# Flutter: Cocoapods error after OS Update to Sonoma 14 and forced migration from XCODE 14 to XCODE 15

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, android-studio, cocoapods

i had a working flutter project (in Android Studio) which i was able to build and deploy to iOS (device, emulator and appstore).

I recently upgraded to Sonoma 14 and was forced to migrate to XCODE 15..

the project can't build anymore with following result:

```
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Error (Xcode): Cycle inside Runner; building could produce unreliable results.
Cycle details:
→ Target 'Runner': CodeSign /Users/xxxxxx/Documents/AppMultiplatform/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app
○ That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”
○ That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script phase “Thin Binary”
○ Target 'Runner' has process command with output '/Users/xxxxxx/Documents/AppMultiplatform/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Info.plist'
○ Target 'Runner' has copy command from '/Users/xxxxxx/Documents/AppMultiplatform/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Share Extension.appex' to '/Users/xxxxxx/Documents/AppMultiplatform/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/PlugIns/Share Extension.appex'
○ That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”


Raw dependency cycle trace:

target:  ->

node: <all> ->

command: <all> ->

node: /Users/xxxxxx/Documents/AppMultiplatform/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/_CodeSignature ->

command: P0:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:CodeSign /Users/xxxxxx/Documents/AppMultiplatform/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app ->

node: /Users/xxxxxx/Documents/AppMultiplatform/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/DKImagePickerController.framework/ ->

directoryTreeSignature: � ->

directoryContents: /Users/xxxxxx/Documents/AppMultiplatform/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/DKImagePickerController.framework ->

CYCLE POINT ->

node: /Users/xxxxxx/Documents/AppMultiplatform/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/DKImagePickerController.framework ->

command: P2:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:PhaseScriptExecution [CP] Embed Pods Frameworks /Users/xxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ckgxhwwvbdtkjfbchnttuutoznaz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-D70BC623FCECD69675274B83.sh ->

node: /Users/xxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ckgxhwwvbdtkjfbchnttuutoznaz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/InputFileList-D70BC623FCECD69675274B83-Pods-Runner-frameworks-Debug-input-files-05c6fbe611d80542646882c2a5c1968e-resolved.xcfilelist ->

command: P2:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/xxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ckgxhwwvbdtkjfbchnttuutoznaz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/InputFileList-D70BC623FCECD69675274B83-Pods-Runner-frameworks-Debug-input-files-05c6fbe611d80542646882c2a5c1968e-resolved.xcfilelist ->

node: <target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49--fused-phase4-thin-binary> ->

command: P0:::Gate target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49--fused-phase4-thin-binary ->

node: <execute-shell-script-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e02f1eee2015e8ff5ebcd27678f788c2826-target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-> ->

command: P2:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:PhaseScriptExecution Thin Binary /Users/xxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ckgxhwwvbdtkjfbchnttuutoznaz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-3B06AD1E1E4923F5004D2608.sh ->

node: /Users/xxxxxx/Documents/AppMultiplatform/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Info.plist/ ->

directoryTreeSignature: a ->

directoryContents: /Users/xxxxxx/Documents/AppMultiplatform/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Info.plist ->

node: /Users/xxxxxx/Documents/AppMultiplatform/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Info.plist ->

command: P0:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:ProcessInfoPlistFile /Users/xxxxxx/Documents/AppMultiplatform/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Info.plist /Users/xxxxxx/Documents/AppMultiplatform/ios/Runner/Info.plist ->

node: /Users/xxxxxx/Documents/AppMultiplatform/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/PlugIns/Share Extension.appex ->

command: P0:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:Copy /Users/xxxxxx/Documents/AppMultiplatform/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/PlugIns/Share Extension.appex /Users/xxxxxx/Documents/AppMultiplatform/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Share Extension.appex ->

node: <target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49--fused-phase6--cp--copy-pods-resources> ->

command: P0:::Gate target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49--fused-phase6--cp--copy-pods-resources ->

node: /Users/xxxxxx/Documents/AppMultiplatform/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/GoogleCastCoreResources.bundle ->

command: P2:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:PhaseScriptExecution [CP] Copy Pods Resources /Users/xxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ckgxhwwvbdtkjfbchnttuutoznaz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-160F4FE231B45515F62A496E.sh ->

node: /Users/xxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ckgxhwwvbdtkjfbchnttuutoznaz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/InputFileList-160F4FE231B45515F62A496E-Pods-Runner-resources-Debug-input-files-e62fecce4bba37b2347c6ae73e74e2f5-resolved.xcfilelist ->

command: P2:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/xxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ckgxhwwvbdtkjfbchnttuutoznaz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/InputFileList-160F4FE231B45515F62A496E-Pods-Runner-resources-Debug-input-files-e62fecce4bba37b2347c6ae73e74e2f5-resolved.xcfilelist ->

node: <target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49--fused-phase5--cp--embed-pods-frameworks> ->

command: P0:::Gate target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49--fused-phase5--cp--embed-pods-frameworks ->

node: /Users/xxxxxx/Documents/AppMultiplatform/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/DKImagePickerController.framework
```

I spend 2 days trying to fix this with little to no success. Still getting the same error. I even tried to do full mac wipe/clean (M1 Mini 16GB) + everything from scratch

Can anyone please explain how to fix this or has any clue on how to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Flutter doctor: [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.6, on macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!